# Android Database: Pre-checking code

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android and I am making my first Android app. In that, I am creating a database. In this app, the first time the app is launched, I am asking the user for a new *password* and confirm the password in mynewscreen. The next time the user launches the app, it asks the user to enter his existing password and check the password in the database.

But in the code, I have error near `checkDataBase()`

My Code:

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
          Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT Password FROM " +
                  "password" +
                  " where Username = 'clicklock'", null);
```

can any one help what is a mistake in  cursor c statement ?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        logm("App started");

        String chreturn=Make_db();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chreturn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        checkDataBase();       

}

 public String Make_db()
    {
   String errormsg = "";
   SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   try {
        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                PASSWORD +
                " (Username VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR);");

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +            PHOTO + " (photoname VARCHAR, photopath VARCHAR,id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);");
           msg ="DatabaseCreated";
       } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        msg ="Not Done Error With Database";
       }
 return msg;

   }
   public  String checkDataBase() {

    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
      Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT Password FROM " +
              "password" +
              " where Username = 'clicklock'", null);

      String password_db = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));
        if(password_db=="")
        {

            Intent i = new Intent(CameraLaunch.this, MyNewScreen.class);                
            startActivity(i);               
        }
        else if(password_db=="123123")
        {               
            Intent i = new Intent(CameraLaunch.this, MyNewScreen.class);                
            startActivity(i);       
        }


      return "working";
    }
     catch (SQLiteException se ) {
         Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
         Make_db();
         return "Could not create or Open the database";
     }        
}
```

Comment: You have a table named password with a field named Password inside it?  Seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply , it's my first testing code , so i have made a table name called Password and inside a table i'm having username , password fields , but it's all working i have a problem in checking weather data already inserted or not , in near  String checkDataBase() {
 anc Cursor lines